# store data outside of a react component and derive state from it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-state

Is it legit to store data outside of a react component and change it from inside the component and derive state from it? This could help when updating complex deep-nested states.

```
import React from "react";

let globalState = {
  foo: { bar: { baz: { value: 0 } } },
};

const Component = () => {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(globalState);
  let baz = globalState.foo.bar.baz;

  const changeValue = () => {
    baz.value += 1;
    setState({ ...globalState });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <label>{state.foo.bar.baz.value}</label>
      <button onClick={changeValue}>change</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

---

### Update:

My main intention of this aproach is to get a cleaner way of updating nested state properties. In my current component I use immer-produce to update nested values of the state, but even with produce it becomes extremely nasty when coming to nested state with arrays, indices etc.

This is an actual code snippet from my application:

```js
const changeAction = useCallback((newAttrs) => {
  setState(
    produce((draft) => {
      draft.newOrders[draft.selectedOrderIndex].nodes[
        draft.selectedNodeIndex
      ].actions[draft.selectedActionIndex] = {
        ...draft.newOrders[draft.selectedOrderIndex].nodes[draft.selectedNodeIndex]
          .actions[draft.selectedActionIndex],
        ...newAttrs,
      };
    })
  );
}, [setState]);
```

Is there any other aproach to clean this up?

Comment: the trouble with this approach is that you're mutating an object in state, rather than replacing it with a new value. You shouldn't ever do this in React, because as far as React is concerned the state hasn't changed (it's the same object reference, just mutated), so it won't rerender.

Comment: This is a very common pattern and there's very, very many tools built on this general idea. The keywords you're looking for are Flux, Redux, etc.

Comment: No, you shouldn't use a global state like that, React has `useContext()` for this instead.

Comment: @RobinZigmond Where am I mutating an object in state? I mutate the "globalState" and the set the local state to its shallow copy {...globalState}. And shouldn't this allways change the reference and trigger a rerender?

Comment: sorry, I missed the shallow copy. This probably does work then, but as other comments have said, there are much better ways of managing your state than doing this.

Comment: @NickParsons What is the advantage of useContext? When I use context I dont have the possibility to directly mutate the "globalState" and allways when globalState changes, my component rerenders, which in my case is not always desired.

Comment: @Maddin By using a global state and using it to derive your component's state, your component is no longer pure. That can lead to confusing bugs (see more [here](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/keeping-components-pure)). It seems odd that you need to mutate your state without that state change needing it to reflect in your UI, you can perhaps consider creating a ref object with `useRef()` if you want to perform updates to a persistent value that doesn't cause rerenders.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like something that would ideally be handled with the use of [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).
Using context can help you manage the state globally rather than mutating objects and passing them up and down the tree all the time, making them difficult to manage.